# abstract algebra one to one and onto

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G= \{(a,b) \mid a,b \in \Bbb Q \  , \ a \neq 0\}$ and a group under the operation $*$ defined by $(a,b)*(c,d)=(ac,ad+b)$

Suppose that $\varphi: G\to G$ defined by $\varphi((x,y))=(x^2,y)$.

> **Question.**  Is it onto?

Answer: I said YES. because suppose $x=(a,b)$ and $y=(c,d)$ Then $\varphi(x)=(a^2,b)=(c,d)$. Recall $\varphi(x)=y$. Since the rationals are closed under regular multiplication, for every $x \in \Bbb Q$, $x^2$ is in $\Bbb Q$. Therefore, $\varphi$ is onto.

Could anyone help me to write a better proof? That's my answer. I understand the concept, but I just can't put it in right words.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Math.SE.  Please edit your question to make the math more readable.  Here's a very accessible tutorial to LaTeX markup.  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  What's the preimage of $(2, 0) \in G$?  In other words, for which $x = (a, b) \in G$ is $\varphi(x) = (2, 0)$?

Mouse over the gray box when you're ready to reveal the solution.

> In order for $\varphi(x) = (2, 0)$, you need $a^2 = 2$ and $b^2 = 0$.  But there is no $a \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $a^2 = 2$.  In different words, the real number $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.  Therefore, $\varphi$ is **not** onto.